# why does this work in c but not in python: (a = 5) == 5

Tags: python, c

New to both python, and fairly beginner in C. Why will the subject code return an error in python?

Does the assignment not have a return value?

Comment: its just python and c are different language so some statements in c will not work in python and vice versa

Comment: C allows it, Python does not. It's a different language after all.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing either, it avoids a very common mistake where you write `if a = b:` instead of `if a == b:`. In C the first is normally not what you want but no error will be thrown leaving a potentially serious bug.

Comment: Thanks all for your speedy support. I now understand that assignments are not used as expressions.

Comment: You could ask why does `int i = 0; i++; printf("%d\n", i);` work in C but not python, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply not valid in Python. You can't use an assignment as an expression.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to expand on Simeon's answer.

First off, you are putting parenthesis around an expression. If you type that into the interpreter by itself you will get a syntax error.  That is because parenthesis are only defined/interpreted in context - there is no context for Python when you are using an expression within the parenthesis.

If you type `(a-5)` then it will attempt to resolve the expression and tell you that a is not defined.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

C's design influenced Python noticeably (check out the string % operator), but some things were rejected because they were a source of errors in C code.  Assignment expressions where one such.  Preincrement and postincrement were rejected for similar reasons, but += (and similar) eventually made it in.

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate this statement, it comes down to

True == 5

Does that make sense anywhere? I don't believe so.